# how to get the value of textbox in the same in php

Tags: php, jquery, html

i am working on textbox in which value is display after selecting value from the combo box .i need to get that value that appear in textbox for further computation in the same page.
 here is the coding

```
<?php

     $options = array(
        '0' => array(
            'title' => ' ',
            'value1' => '',
            'value2' => '',     
        ),
        '1' => array(
            'title' => 'Islamabad',
            'value1' => '31.41',
            'value2' => '73.11',
        ),
        '2' => array(
            'title' => 'Lahore',
            'value1' => '31.56',
            'value2' => '74.35',          
        ),
         '3' => array(
            'title' => 'Kharachi',
            'value1' => '24.86',
            'value2' => '67.01',          
        ),
         '4' => array(
            'title' => 'Faisalâbâd',
            'value1' => '31.41',
            'value2' => '73.11',          
        ),
         '5' => array(
            'title' => 'Gujrânwâla',
            'value1' => '32.16',
            'value2' => '74.18',          
        ),
    );


    if (isset($_GET['option']) && isset($options[$_GET['option']])) {
        echo json_encode($options[$_GET['option']]);
        exit;
    }
?>
<form>
<?php echo "SELECT " ?> 
<select name="combo" id="combo">
<?php

    foreach($options as $key_value => $option)
     {
        printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $key_value, $option['title']);
    }
?>
</select>
<input type="text" name="hidden" id="textboxB" value="" />
<input type="text" name="hidden" id="textboxC" value="" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        $('#combo').change(function(){
            $.getJSON("?", {
                option : $(this).val()
            }, function (data) {
                $('#textboxB').val(data.value1);
                 $('#textboxD').val(data.value1);
                  $('#textboxE').val(data.value1);
                $('#textboxC').val(data.value2);
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

i need to get the value of `textboxB` and `textboxC` in separate variable so that i can use theses value for further computation on the same page.
i want to use theses value in if -else statement like

```
if(textboxD==3.15)
{
$a=$b......
}
```

my requirement is to get these value in separate variable.
people plz help me in ths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your input names to arrays, such as:

```
<input type="text" name="hidden[]" id="textboxA" value="123" />
<input type="text" name="hidden[]" id="textboxB" value="654" />
<input type="text" name="hidden[]" id="textboxC" value="abc" />
<input type="text" name="hidden[]" id="textboxD" value="zyg" />
```

Remember, ID's are only useful for client-side. ID's never get posted, only the NAME and VALUE.

Now, in PHP, you can access these values via:

```
<?php
$hidden = !empty($_POST['hidden']) ? $_POST['hidden'] : false;
if($hidden) {
  foreach($hidden as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value\n"; // 0 => 123, 1 => 654, etc.
  }

  // Directly access single item:
  echo $hidden[3]; // zyg
}
?>
```

Comment: sir the value come on selction from the combo box in the textbox i cant write values by my own

Comment: so i cant write values by my own

Comment: plz help me in this i cant proceed further